# Why is this code working without an Exception

Tags: c#, .net, string, null

At a windows form I call a method at the load event. There I fill some TextBoxes with this:

```
     foreach (TabPage page in tabControl_Berichte.TabPages)
        {
            uc_MusterberichtProzessdetails bla = (uc_MusterberichtProzessdetails)page.Controls[0];

            object val = musterbericht.GetType().GetProperty(page.Name + "_Bem").GetValue(musterbericht, null);
                bla.tB_Bemerkung.Text = val.ToString();

            val = musterbericht.GetType().GetProperty(page.Name + "_Bearb").GetValue(musterbericht, null);
                bla.tB_Bearbeiter.Text = val.ToString();

            val = musterbericht.GetType().GetProperty(page.Name + "_Datum").GetValue(musterbericht, null);
                bla.tB_Datum.Text = val.ToString().Substring(0, 10);

            val = musterbericht.GetType().GetProperty(page.Name + "_Erledigt").GetValue(musterbericht, null);
                bla.chB_Erledigt.Checked = (bool)val;

            val = musterbericht.GetType().GetProperty(page.Name + "_Dauer").GetValue(musterbericht, null);
                bla.tB_Dauer.Text = val.ToString();
        }
```

All the properties are strings except of the "_Datum" which is a DateTime?
When the method is being called, the data will be loaded for each TabPage.

In my example one TabPage is loaded correct. At the 2nd TabPage the Date Property is null. So after this:

```
val = musterbericht.GetType().GetProperty(page.Name + "_Datum").GetValue(musterbericht, null);
```

val is null.

At the next row:

```
bla.tB_Datum.Text = val.ToString().Substring(0, 10);
```

I can see during debugging that when the mouse hovers ToString() there is shown "" (empty string). 
But if I now click F10 my Form will be shown. The method is stoped. The program runs (the following TextBoxes and tabs are not filled with data).

There is NO Exception!! I don't get it. And there is no try catch anywhere.

If I try this directly with an object wich is set to null an exception is thrown.

So what happens here? Why is my program still working??

(Now I test after each val = ... if val != null, so that's not the problem.)

EDIT:

I just tried this out:

```
    DateTime? dttest = null;
    object objtest = dttest;
    string strtest = objtest.ToString();
```

And here I get an exception at ToString().

At the example above I also tried

```
    val = musterbericht.GetType().GetProperty(page.Name + "_Datum").GetValue(musterbericht, null);
if (val.ToString().Length > 0)
    bla.tB_Datum.Text = val.ToString().Substring(0, 10);
```

Here it is almost the same behaviour as above. Here the method stops at the `if (val.ToString().Length > 0)` and the load event is being aborted. (Still no exception)

It looks like `val.ToString()` is working but `val.ToString().xxxxx` will cause this strange behaviour.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` overrode `ToString` not to throw an exception on `null`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is with all the reflection? Does every single instance of your `TabPage` object have a different set of property names? This is certainly non-conventional.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance, as you stated, the `DateTime?` aka `Nullable<DateTime>.ToString()` returns an empty string instead of throwing an exception. This is the answer to the question, so why not post it as an answer?

Comment: The different TabPages can be seen as processes. For each process you can store the same fields (comment, name, date...). These values will be stored in a database (nhibernate object). The database columns are named the same as the tabpages with underscore fieldname. So it's easy for me to load and store the data.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance That could be, but why doesn't the code proceed after this row? The method (the hole load event) stops and the program is running (as if the load event would be in a try block with empty catch)

Comment: +1 for being probably the only question to ask why something is **not** throwing an error. -1 for using exceptions as an expected result - throwing exceptions is very costly, use `null` tests instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket.aspx), or use reflector/dotPeek to see that `Nullable<T>` overrides `ToString()` to return `""` if null, instead of throwing.

`DateTime?` is just `Nullable<DateTime>`, which is why you're getting an empty string and no exception.

**Edit:** The method is probably "ending" when `.Substring(0, 10)` executes because you're going to get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. The empty string has length 0, so you cannot ask for a substring of length 10.

Comment: Thanks, thats right. But there is still no answer why the method ends after when there is a `Nullable<DateTime>.ToString().Substring(10)`?

Comment: The same happens if i do `if (val.ToString().Lenght >0)`. It seems that only `ToString()` is working but `ToString().xxxx` will cause this behaviour.

Comment: Just updated the answer. I can do `val.ToString().Length` just fine, it returns 0. However `val.ToString().Substring(0, 10)` throws an exception, because the empty string has length less than 10.

Comment: Ok you are right, that makes sense. The only question is, why is there no exception at my method?

Comment: what do you mean by "the method ends"? also are you using visual studio or another debugger? you're probably getting an exception and don't realize it. you could add `try {} catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {}` and breakpoint in the catch if nothing else works.

Comment: Or you could change the VS settings to break when an exception is thrown, instead of only breaking on "uncaught" exceptions.  It's what I use if there's bugs in production that don't arise while debugging.

Comment: I'm using VS2012. "the method ends" means during the debugging when the line with the `var.ToString().xxx` is highlighted and I press next step, the program (window) comes to foreground and the program goes on. There is nothing highlighted from the debugger. When I then press a button or anything, the debugging with highlighted codelines goes on. So the rest of my mehtod is ignored.

Comment: @RodMcKay - Have you looked in the output window of VS?  Does anything show up there when you step through this line of code?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thank you very much. I'm very sorry now the question is solved. What I didn't see is that this mehtod is called in a seperate thread. The output shows that an exception occured and this text: `The thread 'VisualizedWorkerDelegate' (0x1568) has exited with code 0 (0x0).` So I think at this thread (which is not my code) the exception will be caught. As j.i.h. already said, I should have enabled the breaking on every exception in the VS settings. Again, thank you all, now I understood what happend!!